# Relationship between cartesian product and cross product?

Tags: terminology, vectors, cross-product

Is there any relation between cartesian product and cross product?
Or is it just the same symbol?

Comment: There are $x$ symbols commonly used in mathematics.  There are $y$ interesting mathematical concepts.  $y \gt x$.  Thus some symbols must be reused.$\ \ \ \ \square\ $

Comment: It's just the same symbol, and definitely not the same thing: the Cartesian product is a set (of vectors), the cross product is a vector.

Answer (score 7):

It is the same symbol used for different concepts; unfortunately there are too many "products" in mathematics.

The "extension" of the *product* operation from *numbers* to *vectors*, gives rise to two different operations; see :

- [Josiah Willard Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs) (1839 – 1903), [Vector Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Analysis) (textbook by E.B.Wilson, first published in 1901 and based on the lectures that J.W.Gibbs had delivered at Yale University); see [pages 55](https://archive.org/stream/vectoranalysiste00gibbiala#page/54/mode/2up) and 60 :

> to introduce two new combinations of vectors. These will be called *products*
>   because they obey the fundamental law of products; i.e., the *distributive* law [...].
>
> *Definition* : The *direct product* of two vectors $A$ and $B$ [denoted : $A \cdot B$] is the *scalar* quantity obtained by multiplying the product of the magnitudes of the vectors by the cosine of the angle between them.  [...]
>
> *Definition* : The *skew product* of the vector $A$ into the vector $B$ [denoted : $A \times B$] is the *vector* quantity $C$ whose direction is the normal upon that side of the plane of $A$ and $B$ on which rotation from $A$ to $B$ through an angle of less than one hundred and eighty degrees appears positive or counterclockwise; and whose magnitude is obtained by multiplying the product of the magnitudes of $A$ and $B$ by the sine of the angle from $A$ to $B$.

---

Regarding the *algebra of sets* operations, terminology has changed over time.

The operations of sets *union* : $A \cup B$ and set *intersection* : $A \cap B$ was originally named *sum* and *product*, respectively, deriving their name from the [Algebra of Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/) of Boole.

Probably, [union](http://jeff560.tripod.com/u.html) is found in 1912 in [James Pierpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Pierpont_(mathematician))'s [Lectures on the theory of functions of real variables](https://archive.org/stream/lecturesonthethe031634mbp#page/n41/mode/2up) (Vol. 2, p. 22).

We can see this in the first modern set theory textbook :

- [Felix Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Hausdorff), [Grundzüge der Mengenlehre](https://books.google.it/books?id=yvVIdH16k0YC&pg=PA23) (1914, Engl.transl. of the 3rd German ed., 1937), page 18 and 23 :

> If $A, B$, are two sets, then by their *sum* [[German 1914](https://archive.org/stream/grundzgedermen00hausuoft#page/4/mode/2up), page 5 : *Summe*], or union,
>
> $$S = A + B$$
>
> we mean the set of all elements that belongs to $A$ *or* $В$ (or both) ; by their *intersection* [German 1914 : *Durchschnitt*]
>
> $$D = AB$$
>
> we mean the set of all elements that belong to both $A$ *and* $B$. [...]
>
> It remains to define the *product* of sets. Let us form from two sets $A$ and $В$ the set $Ρ$ of *ordered pairs* $p=(a,b)$, where $a$ runs through all the elements of $A$ and $b$ runs through all the elements of $B$, [...]. we define the *ordered pair of sets* to be the *set of ordered pairs of elements* [German 1914, page 34 : *Menge der Paare*]. [...] Thus
>
> $$P = (A,B)$$
>
> is the product of the two sets.

[Cartesian product](http://jeff560.tripod.com/c.html) entered circulation in the 1930s. Previously *product*  (*Produkt*) was the established term (see, e.g. F.Hausdorff, *Grundzüge der Mengenlehre* (1914, p. 37)). Kuratowski wrote *produit* for *intersection* and *produit cartésien* for the former *product*.

See [Kazimierz Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazimierz_Kuratowski), [Topologie](https://books.google.it/books?id=WZLOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA7) , Vol.I (1933), page 12 :

> *Définitions*. Le *produit cartésien* (qu'il ne faut, pas confondre avec le produit = partie commune) des ensembles $A$ et $B$ est l'ensemble $A \times B$ composé de tous les couples ordonnés $a,b$ où $a \in A$ et $b \in B$.

See also :

- [Waclaw Sierpinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wac%C5%82aw_Sierpi%C5%84ski), [Algèbre des ensembles](https://books.google.it/books?id=fZFsAAAAMAAJ) (1951), page 62, we have :

> Nous appelons *somme* (ou *réunion*) des ensembles $A$ et $B$ et nous désignons par $A+B$ l'ensemble formé [...]. Nous appelons *produit* (ou *intersection*) des ensembles $A$ et $B$ et nous désignons par $A \cdot B$  l'ensemble [...]

and page 108 :

> Par *produit cartésien* (ou *combinatoire*) de deux ensembles $A$ et $B$, on comprend l'ensemble de toutes les paires ordonnées $(x,y)$, où $x \in A$ et $y \in B$ : un tel ensemble est désigné par $A \times B$.

The final step was to remove the reference to "product" for *intersection*, so to avoid confusion.